# How to get xml response from XMLHttpRequest in iPhone safari browser?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

`XMLHttpRequest` works on most desktop browsers and I am able to retrieve xml response using `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` property but this does not work in iPhone(tested in iPhone6) . I am trying to fetch an XML document from a URL created using `URL.createObjectURL()` . Here is my code:

```
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(largeXMLData);
var xmlXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlXHR.onload = function() {
    try {
        var response = xmlXHR.responseXML;
        if (response == 'undefined' || response == null) {
            alert("No response");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }

};
xmlXHR.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error while getting XML.");
};
xmlXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlXHR.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlXHR.status == 200) {
            alert("Request Complete");
        }
    }
};
xmlXHR.open("GET", blobURL, true);
xmlXHR.responseType = "document";
xmlXHR.send();
```

The `largeXMLData` is blob data which is around 80Mb in size. In iPhone I am getting the 'No Response' alert. Is there a way to get this working in iPhone?

Comment: `largeXMLData` is a string of XML?

Comment: no, it is blob data.